# Spirng @Post method receives data as NULL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have an Web-service to add/edit/update/delete Users and their Notes. When I use @Post method in postman to add a note, it adds its body as NULL. After these values added into database, I use @Put method to update them with the same `Body parameters`, and they are accepted as they should be.

My DTO for Notes looks like this.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NoteDto {
  private int noteId;
  private String topic;
  private String noteBody;
}
```

My `NotesServiceImpl` looks like this:

```
@Override
public NoteDto createNote(int userId, NoteDto noteDto) {
    Note review = mapToEntity(noteDto);

    User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User with associated id not found"));

    review.setUser(user);

    Note newReview = notesRepository.save(review);

    return mapToDto(newReview);
}
```

My Controller for `@Post` method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/user/{userId}/notes")
public ResponseEntity<NoteDto> createNote(@PathVariable(value = "userId") int userId, @RequestBody NoteDto noteDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(noteService.createNote(userId, noteDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

This is how `@Post` output looks like:[image]

Comment: did you add Content-Type: application/json header?

Comment: yes. As I said, I use same headers and body for @Put request, and it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it. The problem was with my `MapToEntity` code. I didn't map Dto properly.

Before it was:

```
`private Note mapToEntity(NoteDto noteDto) {
     Note note = new Note();
        note.setId(note.getNoteId());
        note.setTopic(note.getTopic());
        note.setNoteBody(note.getNoteBody());
        return note;
    }`
```

I changed it to:

```
private Note mapToEntity(NoteDto noteDto) {
    Note note = new Note();
    note.setId(noteDto.getNoteId());
    note.setTopic(noteDto.getTopic());
    note.setNoteBody(noteDto.getNoteBody());
    return note;
}
```

and that solved it.